# How to create a T-SQL query to sum quantity sold per item during a deal period when the sales data is split into multiple tables by month and year

Tags: sql-server

How to create a T-SQL query to sum quantity sold per item during a deal period when the sales data is split into multiple tables by month and year.

I created a simple table name PITEMS that contains 3 columns item_no, start_date and end_date of the promotion.

```
ITEM_NO   START_DATE   END_DATE
-------------------------------
1001      02/25/16     03/25/16
4512      03/01/16     03/31/16
1753      04/10/16     04/28/16
9804      05/01/16     09/10/16
```

Then to calculate quantity sold for item 1001.  I would first have to gather all the data from 2 tables `ITEM_SOLD_022016` and `ITEM_SOLD_032016` for item 1001.

Then I have to sum the quantity that was sold between 02/25/2016 and 03/25/2016.

For item 9804 I would have to combine data from 5 tables.

1. ITEM_SOLD_052016
2. ITEM_SOLD_062016
3. ITEM_SOLD_072016
4. ITEM_SOLD_082016
5. ITEM_SOLD_092016

Comment: Question: how many item sold tables are there and what's the possibility of having a row in PITEMS like start date: 1/1/2000, end date: 12/31/2016?

Comment: Since I will be working with 3 years worth of data, there are 36 sales tables.  There is no chance that the date range in the PITEMs file will be outside of the date range that we're reviewing which is from January 2014 thru December 2016.